# SELECT records based on criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to find a way to select an ID (PersonID) based on criteria. Should this personID not meet the criteria, I need to select another one.  To make it visual I have two tables:
1.

```
ID     Company  LatestOrder
50593   TEST    1
10955   TEST    2
```

2.

```
  ID    Criteria_A  Criteria_B   
 50593    1          0 
 10955    0          0
```

I need to find a way to `SELECT ID` from ``table1 with`latestOrder = 1` Check whether this person meets criteria from table 2 (value 1 for any criteria A or B), then if Yes, select ID from table1 with latestOrder = 2.

And check the criteria as long as table1.lastorder > 0.

Does it makes sense?  I've been bogged with CASE's and IIF's, CTA's but I just cannot seem to find a way to work. I'd love someone to shed some light, in which function direction should I go.

Big thanks for any help guys! This is the 3rd version :(

HERE is where I got so far:

```
WITH LastOrdered AS  
(
            SELECT 
                OrderBillToID AS PersonID
            ,   OrderDate
            ,   OrderBillToCompanyID AS CompanyID
            ,   OrderBillToCompany
            ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ODE.OrderBilltoCompanyID ORDER BY ODE.OrderDate DESC) AS LatestOrder
            FROM dbo.OrderDetails ODE
            INNER JOIN dbo.Persons PER ON ODE.OrderBillToID = PER.ID AND PER.Segment = 'B' AND ODE.OrderBillToCompanyID IS NOT NULL

)
```

Second try

```
SELECT
 PER.ID
 ,  PER.Company
 ,  LatestOrder
 ,  CASE WHEN PER.ExcludeAll = 0 AND (PER.Age > 17 OR PER.Age = 0) AND PER.DateOfDeath = '1900-01-01' AND PER.TLC = 'NA' AND PER.BulkAskExclude = 0 AND PER.EmailExclude = 0 THEN LastOrder
 ....here is when I realised that this case won't work.....
FROM dbo.Persons PER
  INNER JOIN LastOrdered LO ON LO.PersonID = PER.ID
```

EXPECTED output would be:

```
ID     Company  
10955   TEST
```

......

Comment: Post the query you are trying and your expected output with respect to your conditions.

Comment: Thanks Coder! I've edited the post with the query

Comment: Your data and your query do not even match. Please post realistic data.

Comment: Thanks! The CTA and SELECT is one query. Format for some reason separated them.  Let me change to match exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: The rows in Table2 has the same `ID`. Is that correct or typo error?

Comment: yes, that is a typo. let me change it

Comment: Thanks for looking wewesthemenace! :)

Comment: I still can't understand your output. Only `50593` from `Table1` has `latestOrder = 1` and also satisfy the criteria in `Table2`, that is `Criteria_A = 1 or Criteria_B =1`. How do you come up with `10955`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70832/discussion-between-thomas-pollack-and-wewesthemenace).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want the last person who ordered but not does not satisfy any of the criteria in `Table2`:

```
SELECT TOP 1
    id, Company
FROM Table1
WHERE
    id NOT IN(
        SELECT id
        FROM Table2
        WHERE 
            Criteria_A = 1
            OR Criteria_B = 1
    )
ORDER BY LatestOrder DESC
```